# Enable google chat to interact with authenticated Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-chat

I am trying to create a very simple google chat app through cloud function that just echoes a google chat text back to the user. I am following this demo here :https://developers.google.com/chat/quickstart/gcf-app . I followed all the steps but the critical difference is my organization does not allow unauthenticated invocations of cloud function. I provided cloud invoker role to the service account that was automatically created under the name "Google Chat Bot". Cloud function returns a response if I call it from cloud shell but is refusing to work with google chat. In google chat interface, it just say "bot not responding". There are no logs associated with cloud function that would even indicate that google chat is trying to reach the http url.

I am using 2nd gen cloud functions. What roles do I need assign?
Any guidance with troubleshooting it is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried troubleshooting the error by using this [link](https://developers.google.com/chat/troubleshoot/apps#not-responding) as reference?